# Alternative to global variables - GLUT C

Tags: c, window, global-variables, glut, freeglut

I am doing a Dino Race game in C (not C++) and I'm using GLUT for the graphics. I'm having problems because I have to access the x position of a "drawing" from the Display() func and the function that moves it. I can't use global variables so what can I do?

Comment: Isn't the position stored *in* the object, as a member?

Comment: Sorry, I used "object" improperly. I mean that I have an x coordinate of a "drawing" and I have to share it between two functions.

Comment: So make a `struct` which contains everything there is to know about the drawing. Then you pass a pointer to that around your functions, and the image part of the `struct` to the rendering machine.

Comment: Can you make me an exemple? Sorry but I'm quite new to this.

Answer (score 0):

When using glut, you really don't have any option other than to use global variables. Kinda sucks, but there you have it. If you really want to, you can package the variables into a class, something along these lines....

```cpp
class MyGame
{
public:
  MyGame(int argc, char* argv[])
  {
    assert(g_game);
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    // do all the usual glutCreateWindow / glutInitDisplayMode stuff here 

    // attach to the static glut_draw method (which will call draw)
    glutDisplayFunc(glut_draw);
    glutMainLoop();
  }

  void draw();

private:

  /* put your data here */ 

private:
  static MyGame* g_game; //< a single global pointer to your game
  static void glut_draw();
};


MyGame* MyGame::g_game = 0;

MyGame::MyGame(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  assert(g_game);
  glutInit(&argc, argv);

  /* do all the usual glutCreateWindow / glutInitDisplayMode stuff here */

  // attach the 
  glutDisplayFunc(glut_draw);
  glutMainLoop();
}

// use this static method to thunk into the member function draw()
void MyGame::glut_draw()
{
  g_game->draw();
}

void MyGame::draw()
{
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  // you now have access to all the member variables of the MyGame class.

  glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

For bonus points, you can declare draw() as virtual, and hide all of the glut stuff in a base class.

Comment: Thank you, but I found an alternative. I used a struct and assigned its address to the window property, so that I could get it from all the code.

I used this:

void * glutGetWindowData();
glutSetWindowData(void *data);